# How to dot notation in ExpressJS's Jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Assuming that I pass a **userInfo** object in the Jade context and I want to display its **name** property, how would I refer to it using dot notation? I have tried:

```
span Welcome back #{userInfo.name}
```

but it doesn't work. However, this one does

```
span= userInfo.name
```

but I cannot put the 'Welcome back' greeting before it.

NOTE: I don't want to concatenate strings using '+'

Comment: Have you tried putting the content of the span on a new line, indented?

Comment: So what was the problem? Using `userInfo` as the context itself instead of putting `userInfo` **inside** the context object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version should work fine. I tried it out at http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/ and it worked properly. When you say "it doesn't work" what exactly happens? What output do you get? Are you running a recent version of jade? Can you post exactly the context data you are using when rendering the template?

[image]